# Using YCSB on Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, ycsb

I'm trying to use YCSB to load some data into Elastic Search, but I constantly got an error `NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{gdVShcjUToSDe3eJkHJNxw}{192.168.3.87}{192.168.3.87:9300}]]`

Here is my configuration for Elastic Search Node.

```
cluster.name: my-application
node.name: reconf-6
network.host: 192.168.3.87
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
transport.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["elasticsearch-1"]
path.data: data_mount/es
path.logs: data_mount/es
```

I first started 10 nodes like this and by `curl -XGET 'http://elasticsearch-1:9200/_cluster/state?pretty'` I can see 10 nodes are in the cluster.

Then I tried to run YCSB in remote mode. Then it reported exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{gdVShcjUToSDe3eJkHJNxw}{192.168.3.87}{192.168.3.87:9300}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:344)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:242)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:356)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:403)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:392)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1220)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.exists(AbstractClient.java:1242)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.elasticsearch5.ElasticsearchClient.init(ElasticsearchClient.java:142)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:85)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:415)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Part of code starting Client in YCSB is as follows:

```
if (remoteMode) {
  settings.put("client.transport.sniff", true)
      .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", false)
      .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", "30s")
      .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", "30s");
  // Default it to localhost:9300
  String[] nodeList = props.getProperty("es.hosts.list", DEFAULT_REMOTE_HOST).split(",");
  System.out.println("Elasticsearch Remote Hosts = " + props.getProperty("es.hosts.list", DEFAULT_REMOTE_HOST));
  TransportClient tClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings.build());
  for (String h : nodeList) {
    String[] nodes = h.split(":");
    try {
      tClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
          InetAddress.getByName(nodes[0]),
          Integer.parseInt(nodes[1])
      ));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to parse port number.", e);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to Identify host.", e);
    }
  }
  client = tClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to comment out `transport.host` in your configuration file for ES? It binds the transport layer to the localhost and your have already specified the IP of the machine through `network.host`. (you need to restart your node)

Which version of ES are you testing? I saw you left a comment on their [github](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/pull/925) also, so you already know that it won't work with ES 5.x.x. The reason is that ES 5.x.x refuses to connect with the driver for the previous version.

I managed to make it work with the [version of risdenk](https://github.com/risdenk/YCSB/tree/initial-es5).